# How can I get the private key from an RSA public key?

Tags: encryption, encoding, rsa, public-key-encryption

Is is possible to get the private key for RSA encryption given:

```
Public key:
n=14471312083473289027
e=17
```

I found out that:

```
p=2612029591
q=5540255797
```

Now, how do I find `d`??

[This is where I got the description from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078902/cracking-short-rsa-keys)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private key is an integer *d* such that *e*d = 1* modulo both *p-1* and *q-1*. Details are given in the second answer (the one with more than 30 upvotes) to the question you link to.

Comment: how do we find out 1 mod (p-1)(q-1) i.e 1 mod 14471312075321003640 (sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: "_a_ mod _b_" means "the remainder of the Euclidian division of _a_ by _b_". So "1 mod 1447..." is "1". Here, it suffices to find a _d_ such that the product of _e_ and _d_, when reduced modulo _(p-1)(q-1)_, yields 1; this means that _d_ is the _modular inverse_ of _e_. See the [relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). Most libraries for computations on big integers include a function for computing modular inverses (e.g. `BigInteger.modInverse()` if you use the Java programming language).

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the value of d using modular inverse.

Answer (score 2):

RSA Practitioner:

```
e.d=1+k.@n
where k=1,e=17,n=14471312083473289027;
```

find the dataype for n, you will get d ans!

---

```
class temp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int d,e,inc=1;
    datatype n=14471312083473289027;
    e=17;
    n=60;

        do{
            d=(1+(inc*n))%e;
            inc++;
        }while(d!=0);
        System.out.println(inc);

    }
}
```

---

After getting output, add inc to following formula:
then `ans=[((inc-1)*k)+1]/e;`